# Convergence to Dirac delta $ \frac{t}{(t^{1/\alpha} + |x|^2)^{(N+2\alpha)/2}} \to \delta_0 $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Is it true that we have
$$
\frac{t}{(t^{1/\alpha} + |x|^2)^{(N+2\alpha)/2}} \to \delta_0
$$
for $t \to 0^+$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$?

Comment: Try the substitution $x=t^{\frac{1}{2\alpha}}y$ and edit your post with the attempt

Comment: i'm more familiar with notation $\delta(t)$ rather than $\delta_0$ ... have you checked that the integral over $t$ is unity?

Comment: I would not mix and match notations OP. Either use the distribution notation or its equivalent by $\delta_{x_0} = \delta^N(x-x_0)$ but do not use both.